# how to disable showing sql query in django shell?

Tags: python, django

In django's shell always show sql. How to disable this behavior?

```
    In [7]: from .models import Number

    In [8]: Numbers.objects.get(id=1)
    2015-09-17 11:18:48,472 [MainThread  ] [DEBUG]  (0.002) SELECT ... WHERE `numbers`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 21; args=(1,)
    Out[8]: <Numbers>
```

Even if i set

```
LOGGING = {}
```

Comment: Are you using the DjangoDebugToolbar? I believe that is a default behavior of using the dev appserver with that package included in your INCLUDED_APPS. You may also try setting DEBUG = False in your settings.

Comment: @Erik ya, you are right issue was in DjangoDebugToolbar, you can write your comment like answer and i I accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior when using the DjangoDebugToolbar. This can be disabled by writing `DEBUG = False` in your settings after testing for certain environments (say for example you don't want it showing in your staging/prod logs). AFAIK there is no way to have the toolbar running without its DB query logging.